# Discrete math - Mod() : $x^n - y^n$ for $n ≥ 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have been working with modulo for a while now.
But I just saw an equation that I have not been able to solve.

> What are the last digits in $4^n-6^n$ for $n ≥ 0$.
>
> *Hint: This can be solved in many ways, to associate it with the theme, you should try to find a method that uses    mod(10).*

Is someone having a nice article or video lecture about this or perhaps you know how to explain it?

### Solve

Thanks to @Henrik, I started to think of it as smaller pieces.

$4^2 mod(10),6^2 mod(10) => R=6 $  - Not valid

$4^3 mod(10) => R=4 $

$6^2 mod(10) => R=6 $

$n = 3$

Regards,
Petter

Comment: Have you, say, written down the first few?  The pattern is hard to miss.

Comment: Hi @lulu, you mean like $4^1-6^1$, $4^2-6^2$, $4^3-6^3$ and so on? Then yes have written down a few.

Comment: Hint: $4^3\equiv_{10} 4$ and $6^3\equiv_{10} 6$.

Comment: If you have written out a few, then you know what the answer is.  Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik was just thinking of it as a big group and not as individual objects. Guess my mind slipped.

Answer (score 1):

Powers  of $4$ end at $$4,6,4,6,4,6,....$$ and powers of $6$ end at $$6,6,6,6,6,.....$$

Thus $$4^n - 6^n $$ end with $$ 2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,.......$$

Of course we have a sequence of negative numbers ending at these digits.

$$ -2,-20, -152,-1040,.....$$